# Trainer Scheduling Combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, combinations, permutation

I am training to code a solution that allows for the pairing (maybe as a bonus flexibility to to 3,4,5 factorial etc) trainers. The trainers need to be paired each week and then cannot repeat pairing until all combinations have been satisfied. Should be rerunnable for multiple weeks. Should be able to handle odd and even total number of trainers, put in odd because its been more challenging.

I have tried to create all combinations using joins with table 1 < table 2 to find all unique combinations, but am having trouble computing how to pair off without repeating pairs systematically.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Trainer;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Combos;

CREATE TABLE #Trainer
(TrainerID INT)
INSERT INTO #Trainer
(
    TrainerID
)
VALUES
    (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11)

select 
    v.TrainerID as TrainerID1,
    v2.TrainerID AS TrainerID2
 INTO #Combos
from #Trainer V
JOIN #Trainer V2
    ON V.TrainerID < V2.TrainerID2
```

Expected Results would be like follows (sorry for the formatting). Order of output not as important, just that training pairing as not same week to week. EX: 1 and 2 cannot be paired in week 2. Trainer can only be paired once per week:

```
+------+----------+----------+
| Week | Trainer1 | Trainer2 |
+------+----------+----------+
|    1 | 1        | 2        |
|    1 | 3        | 4        |
|    1 | 5        | 6        |
|    1 | 7        | 8        |
|    1 | 9        | 10       |
|    1 | 11       | null     |
|    2 | 1        | 3        |
|    2 | 2        | 4        |
|    2 | 5        | 7        |
|    2 | 6        | 8        |
|    2 | 9        | 11       |
|    2 | 10       | null     |
|    3 | etc      | etc      |
+------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your formatting looks good behind the scenes. Have a look at the [official markdown help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your questions; text between \`\`\`three backticks\`\`\` will display as a big block of code. You can even specify which language to use for syntax highlighting!

Comment: in my humble opinion, this is not a job for a database; this is easy in a wide variety of programming languages, and the modern ones all have database libraries; so : query a straight list of the trainers from the database, and then use customary combination / permutation logic to generate the pairing schedule in code

Comment: Try not to use keyword like Values for database object names to prevent inadvertent errors.